# Command works when copied and pasted but not in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

I'm trying to pass a windows command into a linux netcat shell and then read back the output.

So far I have:

```
cat <( printf 'ipconfig\n' )| nc -v 137.148.70.243 443
```

Which when copied and pasted into my pretty linux terminal gets the ip info from the connected windows machine.

However, when I try to call the same command via bash, I get the following error:

```
./DumpIP.sh: line n: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

What gives?

**EDIT**

So if I try:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <( printf 'ipconfig\n' )| nc -l
```

I get

```
./DumpCreds.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./DumpCreds.sh: line 2: `cat <( printf 'ipconfig\n' )| nc -l'
```

Comment: "line n" ? it might help to see DumpIP.sh

Comment: why `cat` and `printf`? Use a simple `echo ipconfig`.

Comment: @JeffSchaller n is just a placeholder, sorry

Comment: Unable to replicate.  Testing the exact line you have here (with a corresponding `nc -l` on the other side) works exactly as expected.

Comment: @DopeGhoti how strange, I've added my output verbatim in the question

Comment: There's your problem.  You're invoking `sh`, not `bash`.  The `<(command)` syntax is a bashism.

Comment: Doh! You're right, that fixed it. What a trivial yet infuriating problem, now solved thanks to you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you are invoking `sh` and not `bash` for your script in the shebang line.  The syntactical convention of `<(command)` is a bashism that does not exist when invoked via `sh`, which emulates the POSIX shell (if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`).

Comment: Or, rather, is a bashism that is turned off when the Bourne Again shell is operating in its POSIX-compatibility mode.  (Item #28 in the list in the doco.)  After all, the questioner is not using the Bourne shell.  Xe isn't even using the Almquist shell.  Xe is using the Bourne Again shell.  That's a Bourne Again shell error message.  (Almquist and Korn shells present a different message.)

Comment: Also, there is no reason at all to use `cat <( printf 'ipconfig\n' )|` instead of just `printf 'ipconfig\n'|`.